# How to toggle cell icon when clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working with ag-grid where I have a button in cell. I want to change the icon of the button when it is clicked to show some kind of a progress and then return the icon to its original state when the action gets completed.

Here is my code

my-custom.component.ts

```
  <ColDef>{
    headerName: 'Export',
    width: 40,
    height: 80,
    cellRendererFramework: ButtonCellRendererComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      isLoading: false,
      onClick: this.onExportButtonClicked.bind(this),
    }
  }

onExportButtonClicked(cell) {
    this.customService.downloadData(cell.rowData)
      .subscribe(data => {console.log("success")},
        (error) => { console.log("there was an error") },
        () => {
          console.log("complete function triggered");
        });
  }



template: `<button class="unstyled-button" (click)="onClick($event)">
            <span *ngIf="!isLoading">
                <i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="isLoading">
            <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
            </span>
          </button>`,
export class ButtonCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    public isLoading: boolean;

    private params: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.isLoading = this.params.isLoading;

    }
    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        return false;
    }

    onClick($event) {
        if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
            const params = {
                event: $event,
                data: this.params.node.data,
                isLoading: this.isLoading
            }
            this.params.onClick(params)

        }
    }
```

How can I toggle `isLoading` variable here? Is there a way to add callback function to button click?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the structure of your template file, I think it's good.

```
<button (click)="onClick()">
  <span *ngIf="!isLoading">
    ICON1
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="isLoading">
    ICON2
  </span>
</button>
```

In your typescript, I think you can simply initialize `isLoading` to `false`. In your onClick triggered function, just set this attribute to `true`. Then, call your async function and set your attribute to `false` once the task is completed.

```
public isLoading: boolean = false;
public onClick() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.service.taskAsync().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log("success");
    }, (error) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log("error");
    }
  );
}
```

To do not replicate code, you can also use a `pipe`.

```
public isLoading: boolean = false;
public onClick() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.service.taskAsync().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
  ).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log("success");
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("error");
    }
  );
}
```